# Select columns where the percentage of rows with values more than 0 is 75%

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to subset a dataframe like this by selecting only the genes (columns) which are expressed in > 75 % cells, i.e. I want to select only the columns where the percentage of rows with value > 0 is > 75 %. Meaning that in this case, I would end up with genes 1,3,4 and gene 2 would be discarded from the resulting dataframe.

```
x <- read.table(text = "    Gene1   Gene2   Gene3   Gene4
cell1   0   0   0   0
cell2   1   2   1.7 1.5
cell3   2   0   2.5 0
cell4   2.5 0   2.1 2.5
cell5   2   0   0.8 1.5
cell6   3   0   0.5 2.1
cell7   0   0   0   1.2
cell8   0   0   1.6 1.5
cell9   1.6 0   2.3 2.7
cell10  2.4 0   2.1 2.1")
```

How would you resolve this using R ?

Comment: Gene1 is 70% so the result would be Gene3 and Gene4.

Answer (score 1):

Check if it is more than zero, sum columns, then divide by number of rows:

```
colnames(x)[ colSums(x > 0)/nrow(x) > 0.75 ]
# [1] "Gene3" "Gene4"
```